# How does a web page interact with custom hardware on your computer?

Tags: web, hardware

I have a Jawbone ERA Bluetooth headset. An interesting feature about this headset is that, after you install the Jawbone app on your computer, you can visit the jawbone.com website using Chorme and, via the webpage, you can configure the headset via USB. The webpage will detect whether your headset is connected, what the model of headset it is, and display the current configuration and available settings.

My question is: What combination of technologies are used to enable this ability for a web page to communicate with the installed app to configure custom hardware connected to your computer? What is the mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that the app you installed is made to read the cookie data from your site.

It may have also installed a plugin as well.

There are also things that let you use webcams via browser, its kind of similar:  [Can I access the webcam via a browser plugin/add-On?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779549/can-i-access-the-webcam-via-a-browser-plugin-add-on)

There are a few api layers that let you talk to hardware.